# Android Error While Making an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I recently Installed Android Studio 2.1 and started programming. When I tried to create an activity it showed me an error. So guys Help Me to resolve this error and thanks in advance ;)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you try to set it to the same thing you picked as the package name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the package name to "com.example.hina_pc.task1"

As far as I have seen, the correct package name is supplied by default when adding a new activity to a project, so this shouldn't be something that just happens without you changing anything. Essentially, you just want to make sure that the package name of the activity you are adding to the project is the same as the package name of the project.

Comment: You should add some explanation. Better teach fishing than giving a fish.